# Powershell variable issue Get-Content and Get-ADGroup

Tags: powershell, variables, ps1

I'm trying to figure out the reason why I can run the script using variable $groups with Get-Content but it wont work if variable $groups goes with Get-ADGroup list I did below...

Block that works:

```
$groups = Get-Content C:\groups.csv 

$results = @()

$file = "C:\Usuarios_Grupos_Darwin_AD.csv"  

foreach($Group in $Groups) { 

$results +=Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group -Recursive | %{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties Enabled,Name} | Select @{Expression={$Group};Label=”Group Name”},SamAccountName,Name,Enabled

}

$results | export-csv -notypeinformation -Delimiter ";" -path $file
```

Block that's not working:
(only the first line has been changed)

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like '*Darwin*'}  -Properties * | select -property Name

$results = @()

$file = "C:\Usuarios_Grupos_Darwin_AD.csv"  

foreach($Group in $Groups) { 

$results +=Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group -Recursive | %{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties Enabled,Name} | Select @{Expression={$Group};Label=”Group Name”},SamAccountName,Name,Enabled

}

$results | export-csv -notypeinformation -Delimiter ";" -path $file
```

Here is the error:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot create object of type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup". The adapter cannot set the value of property 
"Name".
At line:11 char:34
+ $results +=Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group -Recursive | %{Get-ADUser -Id ...
+                                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

I'm trying to embed the output list all in one script without having to generate csv with another script.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I think it can work if you change the first line : `$groups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like '*Darwin*'}  -Properties * | select -property Name).Name`

Comment: Christophe, that way worked like a charm too ! Thank you brother !! I used this right now for the urgency because it's outputing the groupname without the CN=...... Is there any way I can help u like voting on your profile or something ? I think I cant upvote all answers yet bc I'm a newbie here at stack without many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about your code:

- the `-Filter` parameter should be a string, not a scriptblock
- using `$results +=` is very costly because the entire array needs to be rebuilt in memory on each addition
- `Get-ADGroupMember` can return also computer and (when not used with -Recursive) also group objects, not just users, so you cannot pipe directly to Get-ADUser
- never use `-Properties *` if all you want is one single property

Try this:

```
# Get-ADGroup already returns objects with these properties:
# DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, GroupScope, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*Darwin*'"
$file = "C:\Usuarios_Grupos_Darwin_AD.csv"  
# let PowerShell collect the objects for you instead of using +=
$results = foreach($Group in $Groups) { 
    # Get-ADGroupMember can return objects of type users and computers (also groups when used without -Recursive)
    # so filter the result to get only user objects
    $Group | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Get-ADUser | Select @{Name = 'Group Name'; Expression={$Group.Name}}, SamAccountName, Name, Enabled
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: @Jonathan Please if my answer solved your problem, let us know. Also, since you're quite new to the platform, may I ask you to read the [tour] where you can read how to mark a question 'done'

Comment: Theo, sorry man ! I posted the answer in the wrong place hahaha so it was deleted. Your powershell advices were so helpful man, thank you very much. The only question I had is if is there any way to select only the group name to appear in csv instead of the distinguishedName. It's appearing like "CN=GroupNameblabla OU=XXX DC=Xxxx...."

Thank you !!

Comment: @Jonathan Should be as you want it now. I changed the expression to store the `$Group.Name` instead of the DistinguishedName